# How to save SubMatches as array and print not empty submatches?

Tags: regex, excel, vba

When I try the following Regex code and add a "Add Watch" (Shift + F9) to `Matches`

```
Sub TestRegEx1()
Dim regex As Object, Matches As Object
Dim str As String

str = "This is text for the submatches"
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

regex.Pattern = "Th(is).+(for).+(submatches)|.+(\d)|([A-Z]{3})"
regex.IgnoreCase = True

Set Matches = regex.Execute(str)

End Sub
```

I see that `Matches` is structured like this (with 2 empty submatches):
[image]

2 questions:

How can I save in an array variable the SubMatches?

How can I Debug.Print only elements that are not empty?

I've tried doing like below but is not working

```
Set Arr = Matches.SubMatches
Set Arr = Matches(1).SubMatches
Set Arr = Matches.Item(1).SubMatches
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In your pattern the first part of the alternation matches all 3 values in a group and the second and the third part have not matches. For your example text, you could omit the second and the third part. https://regex101.com/r/gzJy0x/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks for your suggestion. The thing is in my original code I have some alternations, then I apply the Regex.Pattern to different strings and always some submatches are empty.

Comment: `Matches(0).SubMatches(0)` for the first one.

Comment: Do you always expect a single match per input string?

Comment: Hi Wiktor, I apply the same regex.pattern to different strings, then always I'll have let's say, 5 submatches and most of the times within the submatches object will be only one submatch item and the other four are empty but sometimes could be 3 submatches and 2 empty like the example.

Comment: Ok, so, that means 1 match only. Try adding `Dim coll As Collection`, `Set coll = New Collection` and then `If Matches.Count > 0 Then
 For Each m In Matches(0).SubMatches
  If Len(m) > 0 Then coll.Add (m)
 Next
End If`. Then, `coll` should contain all non-empty submatches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the following what you intended? Oversize an array at the start and redim at the end. First version prints only non-empty but stores all. Second version prints and stores only non-empty.

You probably want to .Test to ensure there are matches.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestRegEx1()
    Dim regex As Object, matches As Object, match As Object, subMatch As Variant
    Dim str As String, subMatches(), i As Long
    ReDim subMatches(0 To 1000)

    str = "This is text for the submatches"
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    regex.Pattern = "Th(is).+(for).+(submatches)|.+(\d)|([A-Z]{3})"
    regex.IgnoreCase = True

    Set matches = regex.Execute(str)
    For Each match In matches
        For Each subMatch In match.subMatches
            subMatches(i) = match.subMatches(i)
            If Not IsEmpty(subMatches(i)) Then Debug.Print subMatches(i)
            i = i + 1
        Next
    Next
    ReDim Preserve subMatches(0 To i)
End Sub
```

---

If you only want to store non-empty then

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestRegEx1()
    Dim regex As Object, matches As Object, match As Object, subMatch As Variant
    Dim str As String, subMatches(), i As Long
    ReDim subMatches(0 To 1000)

    str = "This is text for the submatches"
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    regex.Pattern = "Th(is).+(for).+(submatches)|.+(\d)|([A-Z]{3})"
    regex.IgnoreCase = True

    Set matches = regex.Execute(str)
    For Each match In matches
        For Each subMatch In match.subMatches
            subMatches(i) = match.subMatches(i)
            If Not IsEmpty(subMatches(i)) Then
                Debug.Print subMatches(i)
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
    ReDim Preserve subMatches(0 To i)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much for share both options in your solutions. It works pretty fine!

Answer (score 1):

You may use a `Collection` and fill it on the go.

Add

```
Dim m, coll As Collection
```

Initialize the collection:

```
Set coll = New Collection
```

Then, once you get the matches, use

```
If Matches.Count > 0 Then               ' if there are matches
 For Each m In Matches(0).SubMatches    ' you need the first match submatches
  If Len(m) > 0 Then coll.Add (m)       ' if not 0 length, save value to collection
 Next
End If
```

Result of the code with changes:

[image]

Comment: Thnaks so much Wiktor for the alternative solution using Collection.